# Website for tzuras hadaf

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, technology, internet

A couple years ago, I chanced upon a site for creating a tzuras hadaf layout on the Gemara. The website used a custom markup (using tags) to create the layout, and it was a community project that anyone could contribute to. Now I'm looking for it and I can't find it. Does anyone know the name of the site?

Comment: Can you clarify what the goal of the website was?

Comment: I'll second @Menachem's comment. Your "on" is confusing. In any event, welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy it.

Comment: @Menachem: As I recall, the objective of the website was to create a text-based (as apposed to an image), digital print of the Gemara that would be typeset like the standard Vilna print. The website's developers created a tagging system for users to go ahead and contribute with the typesetting. I'm interested in taking a close look at the tagging system they implement.

Comment: I just created this today, might help:
https://shas.newgraphdesign.com/

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but I found this:

http://mekorot.sourceforge.net/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mekorot/files/?source=navbar

Which led to this:

http://www.whatsup.org.il/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=21609

and this:

http://code.google.com/p/tzura/

and this:

http://mekorot.soft112.com/

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this is what you might be looking for:

http://www.themercava.com/dafyomi

Comment: This is it, must be

Answer (score 2):

This site is not tzuras hadaf but it is community editable both text and commentary. http://www.sefaria.org/

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is http://books.613m.org. It's not active and I don't see any links to the source code - but it looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

An amazing resource that I recently found is called "Meforshei HaOtzar" by 'Otzar Hachochma'.

It has tzuras hadaf with section by section clickable to find many meforshim on each specific piece.

[mefo.otzar.org](https://mefo.otzar.org/#/select-page)

NOTE: Both of these resources are currently FREE (due to world quarantine). I imagine that this is for a limited time.

Otzar HaChochma (regular) can be found here: https://www.otzar.org/otzaren/indexeng.asp